# How/what DB should I use to store a queryable list in a database? Linked tables seems very excessive and slow?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I am working on a project that will have millions of primary keys (user IDs). Every user will have a list of attributes of unknown length (between 1 and 100 but generally < 5 in nearly all cases with ~1000 total possible attributes). This list needs to be query-able though to find users with the same attributes.

How would I accomplish this? One method seems to be to create a unique table for every user but this means I would have a LOT of tables which seems wrong. Other method used seems to be storing a list as a blob but this would make querying difficult.

I would prefer to use python but if my rather lightweight server struggles I may switch to c++. The only sql DB I have used so far is SQLite but this may not be ideal as it cannot handle enough commits per second (though I can queue).

What DB should I use and how should I do this properly?

Comment: You can easily store JSON in a PostgreSQL db.

Answer (score 0):

For this scenario i guess **graph based databases** or [GDBs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database) are good options.

You can define your attributes as nodes; one of the famous and powerful graph based databases is [Neo4j](https://neo4j.com/), **Neo4j doesn’t have tables**. Neo4j uses [Cypher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cypher_(query_language)) (graph query language) to handle its query.

**From Neo4j Website:**

> Unlike traditional databases, which arrange data in rows, columns and
> tables, Neo4j has a flexible structure defined by stored relationships
> between data records. With Neo4j, each data record, or node, stores
> direct pointers to all the nodes it’s connected to. Because Neo4j is
> designed around this simple, yet powerful optimization, it performs
> queries with complex connections orders of magnitude faster, and with
> more depth, than other databases.

**From Neo4j website about Cypher:**

> With Neo4j, connections between data are stored – not computed at
> query time. Cypher is a powerful, graph-optimized query language that
> understands, and takes advantage of, these stored connections. When trying to find patterns or insights within data, Cypher queries
> are often much simpler and easier to write than **massive SQL JOINs**.
> Since **Neo4j doesn’t have tables**, there are no JOINs to worry about.

You can find some comparison with SQL in main page of their website: https://neo4j.com/

Check these links too if you want to use Neo4j in python:

1. https://neo4j.com/developer/python/
2. https://pypi.org/project/neo4j-driver/
3. https://towardsdatascience.com/neo4j-cypher-python-7a919a372be7